# using negative keywords with strong target keyword

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results

If I use negative keywords with strong target keyword, which one has targeted by serp the full phrase? or the positive keyword?

Let assume we want to target this keyword "bike parts"

if I create a page called "discounted bike parts" like:

title tab: discounted bike parts

url: mysite.com/discounted-bike-parts

h1: discounted bike parts

So "discounted" keyword is a negative keyword so, serp will exclude this?

and as result, the keyword targeted is "bike parts" so my website will show under "bike parts" results?

and not for ""discounted bike parts" ?

is that the correct approach?

Comment: "Negative keywords" is AdWords terminology.   You could use "discounted" as a negative keyword in AdWords along with the broad match "bike parts".  That would mean that your ad is shown for "bike parts" or "used bike parts" or "where do I get get bike parts", but not for "discounted bike parts".    There is no similar concept for organic search.  There is no way to tell Google NOT to show your page when the query contains certain keywords.

Comment: so for organic, the example will target the full phrase and not the target keyword, in that case, organic should match exactly as the target keyword?

Comment: It doesn't have to match exactly.   I think the answer by @michaeld explains it pretty well.  Titles are important for keywords, but they also need a portion to grab the users attention.   "discounted" could do that, but I wouldn't describe it as a "negative keyword".

Answer (score 1):

I think Google's algorithm works something like this:

If the title of your page is "Discounted Bike Parts", your page topic score might be as follows:

1. Discounted Bike Parts: 10/10
2. Bike Parts: 6/10
3. Discounted Bike: 6/10

So your title is more about "discounted bike parts" than it is about "bike parts".

But this does not necessarily mean that you want to make your title "Bike Parts" just so that you can rank for that exact keywords as a perfect match.

The reason for this is that Google does not want to display identical content in its search results. It does not want to display 10 pages with the exact same title of "Bike Parts". It wants to show some pages with "Discounted Bike Parts" and "Bike Parts for Sale".

It is important to have the keywords that you are targeting in your title, but you do not need to go overboard in trying to exact match the search keywords. Google will understand what your page is about.

There may be a slight ranking boost by having the keyword that you are targeting before your negative keywords. For example, "Bike Parts Store" might be better optimized than "Discounted Bike Parts" because the keyword comes first.

Ultimately, Google will try to rank pages that it thinks are the absolute best page on the internet for what the searcher is looking for. Optimizing keywords and keyword density to target a search phrase is important, but it's much more important that your page is the best page on the web for your topic. If Google believes that you have the best page for its customers when they search for "Bike Parts", it should rank "Discounted Bike Parts".